# Not able to _include Organization resource for MedicationRequest resource

Tags: hl7-fhir

My medication request resource contains a reference to Organization resource:

```
           "requester": {
                "agent": {
                    "reference": "Practitioner/12345",
                    "display": "Abhishek Nayyar"
                },
                "onBehalfOf": {
                    "reference": "Organization/56789",
                    "display": "XYZ Hospital"
                }
            },
```

I want to fetch this Organization Resource along with medication request resource using a single api call. I am doing this:

GET https://FhirServerBasePath/MedicationRequest?subject:Patient.identifier=1358&_include=MedicationRequest:requester:Organization

However, in the response, I am not getting organization resource. When I try to use the same query for Practitioner (which is also referenced under requester), I am able to fetch it successfully.

Answer (score 0):

In STU3, the MedicationRequest `requester` search parameter only looks at MedicationRequest.requester.agent.  There is no 'standard' search parameter that looks at MedicationRequest.requester.onBehalfOf, which means that unless the server supports a custom search parameter based on that element, there's no way to do an _include for it.

Comment: Thanks! Just for my reference can you please point me to the HL7 FHIR website page where this is mentioned. I have been searching the website alot to find what you just wrote.

Comment: The list of defined search criteria for MedicationRequest is [here] (http://hl7.org/fhir/STU3/medicationrequest.html#search).  If you look at the 'requester' search parameter, you can see that the expression for it is `MedicationRequest.requester.agent`.  In the section on [search](http://hl7.org/fhir/STU3/search.html#revinclude) it clearly says "Both _include and _revinclude are based on search parameters, rather than paths in the resource".

Comment: Right..except that in the R4 version it just mentions Medication Request.requester. So, this means if the FHIR server is R4 I should be able to retrieve organization resource as well. Am I right in saying so?

Comment: In R4, there is no 'onBehalfOf'.  If you need the Organization a Practitioner acted on behalf of, you must chain through PractitionerRole.  If you need the Organization a Device acted on behalf of, you chain through Device.